# How to include "discriminator" column with single child class

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have an abstract base class that has a single child. A table is successfully created for the base class and is populated with the child data.

However, there is no discriminator column.

If I create another child class and re-run migration, EF creates the discriminator column. It also runs the *Seed* method and recreates my initial records, because it no longer sees the existing data (because the new discriminator is blank for existing records)

We will add more child classes in the future. I want to have the discriminator now (in the beginner) to prevent data problems when we add these new classes.

Using entity framework 6 (TPH) on .NET 4.5

Comment: Maybe it'll be helpful to see your seed. You might need to change your seed to get it to work. Another option is to make sure the seed doesn't run unless you're creating a new database if that works for your use case.

Comment: What is a `discriminator` column?

Comment: Sam: it's the default name of a column EF uses to differentiate different classes (parent, children) stored in a single table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the value of the discriminator column using fluent api in the `OnModelCreating` override (and this will ensure EF adds the column in your scenario):

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Child>()
   .Map<Child>(m => m.Requires("Discriminator").HasValue("Child"));
```

You can also change the name of the Discriminator column if you want:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Course>()  
    .Map<Course>(m => m.Requires("Type").HasValue("Course"))  
    .Map<OnsiteCourse>(m => m.Requires("Type").HasValue("OnsiteCourse"));
```

Reference:

[Mapping TPH inheritance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/jj591617.aspx#2.4)